Make (a quite simple) pyparsing based parser fault tolerant
I wrote a little parser using pyparsing to parse Google-like search strings, like foo AND (bar OR baz) (full code below). Like Google, I would like to make the parser fully fault-tolerant. It should ignore errors and parse as much as it can.
I wonder if I should adapt my grammar somehow (which looks very hard to me) or add some preprocessing to make the search string always valid when it gets parsed (but there are quite some corner cases; see invalid expressions in tests below).
I also thought about using pyparsing's search_string instead of parse_string which never seems to raise an exception, but the output is often not really useful for my use case (e.g. foo AND OR bar => [[TermNode(WORD, foo)], [BinaryNode(OR, TermNode(WORD, ND), TermNode(WORD, bar))]])
import pyparsing as pp
from typing import Literal

class TermNode:
  def __init__(self, term_type: Literal["WORD", "PHRASE"], value: "Node"):
    self.term_type = term_type
    self.value = value

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"TermNode({self.term_type}, {self.value})"

class UnaryNode:
  def __init__(self, operator: Literal["NOT"], operand: "Node"):
    self.operator = operator
    self.operand = operand

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"UnaryNode({self.operator}, {self.operand})"

class BinaryNode:
  def __init__(self, operator: Literal["AND", "OR"], left: "Node", right: "Node"):
    self.operator = operator
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

  def __repr__(self):
    return f"BinaryNode({self.operator}, {self.left}, {self.right})"

Node = TermNode | UnaryNode | BinaryNode

not_ = pp.Keyword("NOT")
and_ = pp.Keyword("AND")
or_ = pp.Keyword("OR")
lparen = pp.Literal("(")
rparen = pp.Literal(")")

extra_chars = "_-'"
word = ~(not_ | and_ | or_) + pp.Word(pp.alphanums + pp.alphas8bit + extra_chars).set_parse_action(lambda t: TermNode("WORD", t[0]))
phrase = pp.QuotedString(quoteChar='"').set_parse_action(lambda t: TermNode("PHRASE", t[0]))
term = (phrase | word)

or_expression = pp.Forward()

parens_expression = pp.Forward()
parens_expression <<= (pp.Suppress(lparen) + or_expression + pp.Suppress(rparen)) | term

not_expression = pp.Forward()
not_expression <<= (not_ + not_expression).set_parse_action(lambda t: UnaryNode("NOT", t[1])) | parens_expression

and_expression = pp.Forward()
and_expression <<= (not_expression + and_ + and_expression).set_parse_action(lambda t: BinaryNode("AND", t[0], t[2])) | (not_expression + and_expression).set_parse_action(lambda t: BinaryNode("AND", t[0], t[1])) | not_expression

or_expression <<= (and_expression + or_ + or_expression).set_parse_action(lambda t: BinaryNode("OR", t[0], t[2])) | and_expression

#or_expression.parse_string('', parse_all=True)
or_expression.run_tests("""\
  ###
  # Valid expressions
  ###

  # Word term
  foobar

  # Umlaute in word term
  Gürtel

  # Phrase term
  "foo bar"

  # Special characters in phrase
  "foo!~ bar %"

  # Implicit AND
  foo bar

  # Explicit AND
  foo AND bar

  # Explicit OR
  foo OR bar

  # NOT
  NOT foo

  # Parenthesis
  foo AND (bar OR baz)

  # Complex expression 1
  NOT foo AND ("bar baz" OR qux)

  # Complex expression 2
  foo AND (NOT "bar baz" (moo OR zoo) AND yoo)

  # Complex expression 3
  foo (bar NOT "baz moo") zoo

  ###
  # Invalid expressions
  ###

  # Unary before binary operator
  foo NOT AND bar

  # Invalid redundant operators
  foo AND OR bar

  # Unknown char outside quoted terms
  foo ~ bar

  # Binary operator at start of line
  AND foo

  # Binary operator at start of parens expression
  (AND bar)

  # Binary operator at end of line
  foo AND

  # Binary operator at end of parens expression
  (foo AND)

  # Unary operator at end of line
  foo NOT

  # Unary operator at end of parens expression
  (foo NOT)

  # Unbalanced parens
  ((foo)

  # Unbalanced quotes
  ""foo"
""");


Semicolon??? What is this, Javascript?

If you define a catch-all expression and then add it to your main parse expression, it won't "fix" everything, but you'll get a few more parsed terms.
error_parse = pp.Word(pp.printables).suppress()
expr = (or_expression | error_parse)[...]

Try running expr against your invalid cases.

Yes, this leads to better results than using search_string, so +1. Unfortunately, it's still not good enough for my case and may even be impossible without more extensive manual grammar adjustments. I ended up preprocessing the string, which took quite some time as there were so many corner cases.
